# SharePoint Online REST API Image upload AJAX

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm trying to upload an image to SharePoint using native JavaScript/jQuery - NOT SP.RequestExecutor.

I've cracked the authentication issue, nice and easy, so now it's just a case of working out how to upload binary files. If I put plain text in the file, it uploads fine, it's just binary data I'm having trouble with.

My code so far is included below. `getToken()` does it's thing and leaves me with a valid digest object to use. Also note I've blanked out the document library name with `*`'s.

```
function PerformUpload(fileName, fileData) {    
    getToken();
    $.ajax({
        url: siteFullUrl +
        "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/*****/')/Files" +
        "/Add(url='" + fileName + "', overwrite=true)",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: fileData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": digest
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: \r\n" + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried many combinations of different values for `contentType`, setting `binaryStringRequestBody: true` but the image is still corrupt when it comes into SharePoint.

My code at the moment to parse the file into binary is

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (result) {
    var fileName = '',
     libraryName = '',
     fileData = '';

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(result.target.result)
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        fileData += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i])
    }
    PerformUpload("image.jpg", fileData);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);
```

A file is being uploaded to SharePoint but if I try and view or download it it's corrupt.

Can anyone provide any guidance as to the correct way to upload a binary file to SharePoint? I should mention that if I replace (on the ajax call) `data: fileData,` with `data: "A simple string",` the file uploads and when I download it the contents of the file are `A simple string`.

Answer (score 2):

the problem can is here : `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);`

where the fileInput is the type of file, if you setting "filelist" you will get file corrupted, check this correctly, converting to "File".

An example:

```
        var element = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        var fileInput = element.files[0];
```

and add to ajax properties:

```
binaryStringRequestBody:true;
```

And tell me if resolved this question.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which uses SPServices (instead of the standard rest api) to upload a binary file from clipboard (only works on chrome at this point due to clipboard api)

http://pastebin.com/yR6jzxu6

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to get this working using native JavaScript/jQuery though, so SPServices is not an option :(

Comment: spservices is a jquery addon for interfacing with the shareoint api.

Comment: Please do not use pastebin, it is easy enough to add your code snippets directly to your post. That way future readers can get help from your answer even if the pastebin link is broken :)

Comment: Does it use REST though?

Comment: No it uses SOAP I believe, http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a file is uploaded, Sharepoint adds some metadata to it and corrupts the file. 
You need to add a setting to tell Shrepoint not to modify the file

```
transformRequest: []
```

Here is a snipper of my code that works:

```
function uploadAttachment(file) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var cache = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
            var cfg = $formsConfig;
            var url = cfg.web() + "_api/web/Lists(guid'" + cfg.listId() + "')/items(" + $formsConfig.itemId() + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')";
            digestValue.getDigestValue().then(function (digest) {
                $http.post(url, cache, {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    transformRequest: [],
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                    }
                }).success(function (data) {
                    dfd.resolve(data);
                }).error(function () {
                    dfd.reject();
                });
            });
        };
        reader.onerror = function (event) {
            console.error("File reading error " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        return dfd.promise;
    }
```